# Preventing multiple activities from stacking with a camera snap

Tags: android, menu, stack-overflow, return, back

I have read into the `finish();` commands and the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` commands and also checked out Common Ware's answer on killing app, but I am not sure how to put this into my app.

Basically, I have a user click a button that takes them to the camera.  The user then snaps a photo and it brings them to a layout view.  The user then clicks a button that takes them to one of 2 views, depending on a some conditions.

The user is then allowed to either retake a photo, or go to the main menu (depending).  My problem is, if the user goes back to the main menu, and snaps another, then another, etc...the activities stack, so when I click the 'Main Menu' button the app goes back through eached stack activity until finally it goes back to the main menu.  Is there a way to kill each activity with one of these lines, so even if a user retakes a photo, they will only need to go back once to get to the main menu?

Thanks for anyhelp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [noHistory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) flag which would end each activity once you're away from it. 
Probably though, what you really want is [singleTop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) launch mode, that will return to your previously opened activity rather than making a new instance of it.